# Commit logs and hints directory are getting filed up and not rotating

Tags: java, database, cassandra

Our commitlogs in cassandra cluster are increasing and it's not getting rotated. Even the hints directory continues to grow and after some hours the node gets completely filled up. We have to manually flush and drain the nodes in order to keep the cluster up.
We are continuously seeing the following error in the Cassandra system.log

```
ERROR [CommitLogArchiver:1] 2023-07-28 17:27:19,289 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[CommitLogArchiver:1,5,main]

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Exception while executing the command: ln /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-*****.log /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-*****.log, command error Code: 1, command output: ln: failed to create hard link ‘/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-****.log’: File exists
```

Update 1: More logs

```
...
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception while executing the command: ln /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690545624564.log /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690545624564.log, command error Code: 1, command output: ln: failed to create hard link ‘/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690545624564.log’: File exists
.
.
.

WARN  [CompactionExecutor:80864] 2023-07-28 18:31:35,403 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition *****:***_490267998772576797 (124.548MiB) to sstable /cassandra/data1/**/event_source-0b510d8003e811ecb8bb3d20c002593b/md-15942-big-Data.db
INFO  [ReadStage-3] 2023-07-28 18:32:03,841 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (536870912), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:80864] 2023-07-28 18:32:36,245 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition ***/***:2023-07-28:61:com.Ticket (112.067MiB) to sstable /cassandra/data1/****/****-869ff7d3f4d711ed9031839535e0fa8e/md-1381-big-Data.db
...

INFO  [HintsDispatcher:8394] 2023-07-28 18:44:12,914 HintsDispatchExecutor.java:282 - Finished hinted handoff of file 7c57e613-f0c6-4f67-9da5-3cfaad15de29-1690397494422-1.hints to endpoint /100.125.114.117: 7c57e613-f0c6-4f67-9da5-3cfaad15de29
INFO  [ReadStage-2] 2023-07-28 18:47:05,188 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (536870912), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:80867] 2023-07-28 18:47:24,120 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition ***/event_source:comTicket:***_998981534549995600 (166.860MiB) to sstable /cassandra/data1/****/***-0b510d8003e811ecb8bb3d20c002593b/md-15947-big-Data.db
...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen before.  This means that your cluster is taking more writes than it can keep up with.  Eventually what happens, is that the nodes get overwhelmed, stop accepting writes due to the backpressure, and eventually start rejecting them.  This causes the other nodes to accumulate hints.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Exception while executing the command: ln /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690554222773.log /cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690554222773.log, command error Code: 1, command output: ln: failed to create hard link ‘/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1690554222773.log’: File exists

Now, I haven't seen that particular error.  Although it seems to suggest that a commitlog file can't be properly hard-linked.  TBH I think it's more of a symptom rather than a cause.

Have a look at your metrics.  When this happens, CPU usage tends to go and stay high.  As for fixing this, there are a couple of options:

- **Throttle-down the write load**. An easy way to do this, is to put an event streamer / message broker (like Pulsar or Kafka) in-between the writing application and the cluster. Then, build a consumer to grab the messages and write them into Cassandra.
- **Add more nodes**.  Probably the most likely scenario, is that the current cluster doesn't have the resources necessary to process the current write load.  If you're deploying in a public or private cloud, this should be pretty easy to do.
- **Adjusting `memtable_flush_writers`**.  It's possible that the default of 2 isn't right for your cluster's load.  Read through the comments in the `cassandra.yaml` file, but if I remember right, reducing the number of flush writers should increase flush activity.  From what I'm reading though, I don't think adjusting this setting will be enough, but it's worth a try.

**TL;DR;**

- Decrease the amount of writes coming in.
- Increase the cluster nodes.
- Adjust `memtable_flush_writers` in the `cassandra.yaml` file (requires restart of all nodes).

Comment: The formula is memtable_cleanup_threshold = 1 / (memtable_flush_writers + 1), so we should decrease the memtable_flush_writers value, right? So that memtable_cleanup_threshold will increase

Comment: Or it should be the other way round? I should increase the memtable_flush_writers, so that memtable_cleanup_threshold would decrease and we will see quicker/more frequent memo flush activity

Comment: I have attached more logs

Comment: @user101 Yes, I would start by _decreasing_ memtable_flush_writers down to 1.